# How do I create a pool of lists that are thread safe in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Old title: Is an array of lists thread safe in C#?
I try to use a pool of lists for parallel processing. I create lists in an array and then use a ConcurrentBag of integers to allocate them to threads. Since the entire code is quite long I made an excerpt. In the below example each thread would need 5 lists of object x.

```
int maxThreads = 64;
ConcurrentBag<int> pool = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
// Populate ConcurrentBag with values 0 through 63
for (int i = 0; i <= maxThreads - 1; i++)
{
     pool.Add(i);           
}
List<x>[,] ABCList = new List<x>[maxThreads, 5];
Parallel.ForEach(zList,
new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads },
p =>
{
     while (!pool.TryTake(out slot));
     // Do something here with ABCList[slot, 1....5]
     // Example: ABCList[slot, 1].[1].Field1 = 2;
     // Example: ABCList[slot, 1].[1].Field2 = "abc";
     pool.Add(slot);
});
```

So this runs without an error or any warnings. However inside parallel processing it sometimes fails to update values in ABCList[slot, 1....5]. By sometimes I mean 2-5 cases out of 1000. When I check in debug mode I can't reproduce the symptom. When I press F11 the list values are updated.
Please consider that I'm a hobby programmer and I may do something obviously wrong here. Any ideas how to do this correctly?
**EDIT**
Based on the suggestion of Peter I rewrote like this:

```
int maxThreads = 64;
ConcurrentBag<int> pool = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
ConcurrentDictionary <int, List<x>[]> ABCList = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<x>[]>();
// Initialize ConcurrentDictionary
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
{
     pool.Add(i);
     ABCList[i] = new List<x>[5];
     for (int w = 0; w <= 4; w++)
     {
          ABCList[i][w] = templateABCList[w].ConvertAll(p => p);
     }
}
Parallel.ForEach(zList,
new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads },
p =>
{
     while (!pool.TryTake(out slot));
     // Do something here with ABCList[slot][1...5]
     // Example: ABCList[slot][1][1].Field1 = 2;
     // Example: ABCList[slot][1][1].Field2 = "abc";
     pool.Add(slot);
});
```

The problem still exists. The list fails to update in some cases. What do I do wrong?

Comment: An array in general is not completely thread safe, so you should make it thread safe; better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: They clearly aren't, so what are you really asking here?  Adjust your title accordingly.

Comment: From what I can see you almost ran 90% of the way by using the ConcurrentBag. Why not use the ConcurrentDictionary for the rest of it? Each key in the dictionary would be the "slot", the value of each key points then to a List<x>: ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<x>>.

Comment: I implemented the change suggested by @PeterBranforn and posted as an edit.

Comment: Ok, I see there is a general issue: you access the list in a not supported way, is there a reason you are using "TryTake()"? The original documentation of "ForEach" requires you to pass in the list you are editing and access each element by the lambda parameter "(p)" like this: "(p)[1][1].Field1 = 2; The "tryTake" is assuming you modify the pool array, but you are actually modifying an entirely different array. It looks to me as if you are trying to use the pool as synchronisation object, which will not function.

Comment: Let me give an example what I try to do.Let's say I receive integer 3 from the ConcurrentBag. I take it out and with this the intention is to get a unique slot for that thread. Then this thread would work with ABCList[3][ ] that is an array of 5 lists and only used by this thread. Once the thread is finished it puts back integer 3 to the ConcurrentBag. ABCList[3][ ] has it's values changed and it remains like that. Then next loop of ForEach starts and maybe receives 3 again from the ConcurrentBag. Then the whole process starts again it re-populates ABCList[3][ ] by overwriting everything in it

Answer (score 0):

You can Use System.Collections.Concurrent Name Space for Thread Safe Collections,
[and you can Use ConcurrentBag Class to Create Object(List) Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-create-an-object-pool)

if you want Any list in pool is Thread safe , you can Use

```
var threadSafeArrayList = ArrayList.Synchronized(new ArrayList());
```

For Create each List Object